# Question about meaning of "winter formal" & " vibrating" & "anticipation" & "senior" in this text

Tags: word-meaning

> William had no girlfriends in high school, and his mother once sat him down at the table in her spotless kitchen and asked if he was gay. She said it would be fine with her. She loved him unconditionally, and they would figure out a way to tell his father. But William wasn’t gay. He was just absurdly, painfully in love with Bridey Taylor, who leaned on the piano and sang while he played, and he had no way of telling her. He was too shy to pursue other girls, even when the payoff seemed either likely or worth the agony. But he didn’t tell his mother that. It was too humiliating. He just stammered an unconvincing denial.
>
> Other boys asked Bridey out, and William suffered through it. She viewed them with amusement, but she accepted most invitations. Encouraged, in their junior year William decided to ask her to the **winter formal** .He was getting ready, **vibrating with anticipation**, when Bridey told him that a tennis-playing **senior** named Monty had invited her.

A milion thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see a single word in bold that couldn't be looked up in a dictionary such as [this one](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/). And there are plenty more online dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this answers your questions, let me know if I can expand on any part of it.

**Winter Formal**

A winter formal is a type of formal dance in high school, similar to prom or homecoming.

**Vibrating with anticipation**

This is a metaphor, to show that he is super excited to go. In other words, he can barely contain his excitement.

**Senior**

"Senior" is another word for a 12th grader, the last year of high school in the United States. Just for good measure, ninth graders are called freshmen, tenth are Sophomores (soff-more), eleventh are juniors, and twelfth are seniors. That naming convention is also present throughout the four years of typical university, in the same order.

Comment: -Thanks a lot. I am just wondering if you could tell me what is supposed to happen in a Winter Formal.

Comment: @user5036 It's a get-together (a party, of sorts) for the entire class, where people dress up in formal attire. There's a dance floor, although dancing is optional. People often take dates. I'm trying to think of some more ways to describe it, but that's what's coming to mind now.